# Error: no method named `parse` found for enum `Result` in the current scope

Tags: file, parsing, vector, rust, integer

I'm trying to read a txt file with numbers like 1234 823, I want to convert those into an `u16` and `.collect()` them into a vec. It gives me this error: `no method named "parse" found for enum "Result" in the current scope`. So how can i fix this?

```
let file_in = fs::File::open("input.txt").unwrap(); 
let file_reader = BufReader::new(file_in); 
let vec: Vec<u16> = file_reader.lines().map(|x| x.parse::<u16>().unwrap()).collect();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`lines` returns an iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) which yield [instances of `io::Result<String>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html). So you can [`unwrap` instance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) to get the  contained [`Ok` value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Ok).

```
let vec: Vec<u16> = file_reader
    .lines()
    .map(|x| x.unwrap().parse::<u16>().unwrap())
    .collect();
```

But this will panic if any of the line is failed to parse(to `u16`). So you can use [`filter_map` instead.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map)

```
let vec: Vec<u16> = file_reader
    .lines()
    .filter_map(|x| x.unwrap().parse::<u16>().ok())
    .collect();
```

Comment: ...and this will panic if there was error reading the line. You can use `.filter_map(|x| x.ok()?.parse::<u16>().ok())` instead.

Comment: Using `filter_map()` for errors in either `parse()` or `lines()` will cause errors to be **silently** dropped. Normally best practice is to stop on first error, e.g. by collecting to `Result`. Here it gets a bit complicated because the error returned by `parse()` and by `lines()` are different, so it requires some gluing, as [shown here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=862ac25169f795b67d6f3849d2efadd7). If the OP is doing AOC exercises, an `unwrap()` will probably do.